# How to Show Additional y-axis and need to bind line series to it in JqPlot

Tags: javascript, jqplot

i'm developing an windows store app using JavaScript,in which i'm showing data in graphically(like charts,table).In one of the charts i need to show two y-axis's and i'm having four series(two bar-series and two line-series)the bar series need to bind to left side y-axis and line series nee to bind to right side y-axis.

FYI
[image]

like i need,any sample code is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the below code which i used in one of the application, i hope this will help you. In the below code i'm using ajax calls i'm parsing the request to json and that dataset i'm using to jqplot chart.

```
        var barseries = new Array();
        var lineseries = new Array();

        var barseries2 = new Array();
        var lineseries2 = new Array();

        var Items = JSON.parse(xhAreaName.responseText);//Parsing the xhr response to json

        for (var i = 0; i < Items.GetChartDataResult.length; i++) {
            barseries[i] = new Array(2);
            lineseries[i] = new Array(2);

            barseries2[i] = new Array(2);
            lineseries2[i] = new Array(2);

            barseries[i][0] = Items.GetChartDataResult[i].AreaName;
            barseries[i][1] = Items.GetChartDataResult[i].Actual * 1000;

            barseries2[i][0] = Items.GetChartDataResult[i].AreaName;
            barseries2[i][1] = Items.GetChartDataResult[i].Budget * 1000;

            lineseries[i][0] = Items.GetChartDataResult[i].AreaName;
            lineseries[i][1] = Items.GetChartDataResult[i].AttainValue * 100;

            lineseries2[i][0] = Items.GetChartDataResult[i].AreaName;
            lineseries2[i][1] = Items.GetChartDataResult[i].Target * 100;

            $('.jqplot-series-' + i).css('color', '#ffffff');

        }

        var plot1 = $.jqplot('AreaNameChart', [barseries, lineseries, barseries2, lineseries2], {
            series: [{ renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer }, { xaxis: 'x2axis', yaxis: 'y2axis' }, { renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer }, { xaxis: 'xaxis', yaxis: 'y2axis' }],
            seriesDefaults: {
                pointLabels: { show: true },
                rendererOptions: { fillToZero: true }
            },
            axesDefaults: {
                show: false,
                tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                rendererOptions: {
                    drawBaseline: false
                }
            },
            grid: {
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                color: 'White'
            },
            //legend: {
            //    show: true,
            //    placement: 'outsideGrid'
            //},
            axes: {
                xaxis: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                    tickOptions: {
                        showGridline: false
                    }
                },
                x2axis: {

                    renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                    tickOptions: {
                        showGridline: false,
                        showTicks: false
                    },
                    labelOptions: {
                        show: true,

                    },
                },
                yaxis: {
                    pad: 1.05,
                    tickOptions: { formatString: '$%d', showGridline: false, labelPosition: 'middle' }
                },
                y2axis: {
                    tickOptions: { formatString: '%d%', showGridline: false, labelPosition: 'middle' }
                }
            },
            seriesColors: ["#1e98e4", "#98b954", "#ffc500", "#695188"],
```

Answer (score 0):

Here an example on how you can use 2 `Yaxis` in `JqPlot`:
[JsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/KW5rJ/1/)

```
$.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;
var chartData = [["19-Jan-2012", 2.61], ["20-Jan-2012", 5.00], ["21-Jan-2012", 6.00]];
var chartData1 = [["19-Jan-2012", 20], ["20-Jan-2012", 30], ["21-Jan-2012", 50]];

function PlotChart(chartData, extraDays) {

    var plot2 = $.jqplot('chart1', [chartData,chartData1], {
        title: 'Mouse Cursor Tracking',
        seriesDefaults: {

            pointLabels: {
                show: true
            }
        },
        series:[
            {
                yaxis:'yaxis'   
            },
            {
                yaxis:'y2axis'   
            }
            ],
        axes: {
            xaxis: {
                pad: 1,
                // a factor multiplied by the data range on the axis to give the            
                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                // renderer to use to draw the axis,     
                tickOptions: {
                    formatString: '%b %#d',
                    formatter: $.jqplot.DateTickFormatter
                }
            },
            yaxis: {
                tickOptions: {
                    formatString: '$%.2f'
                }
            },
            y2axis: {
                tickOptions: {
                    formatString: '$%.2f'
                }
            }
        },
        highlighter: {
            sizeAdjust: 7.5
        },
        cursor: {
            show: true
        }
    });
}

PlotChart(chartData, 3);
```